# Exit Python RFID Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, python-multithreading, rfid

I have started a small project and am currently stuck on a problem.
I have written a small GUI in Tkinter which opens another thread when the button is pressed in order to read the ID of an RFID chip. This is then returned to the GUI via a queue object and displayed there by the label. This works so far.

Now I would like to implement that the thread is terminated when no RFID chip has been detected for 10 seconds or the thread still exists after this time. I have tried to interrupt this with an event as follows but without success.

Does anyone have an idea how this could work?

Thanks already.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tkinter as tk
import queue
import threading
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522

class GUI:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.test_button = tk.Button(self.master, command=self.tb_click)
        self.test_button.configure(text="Start", background="Grey", padx=50)
        self.test_button.pack(side='top')
    
        self.test_label = tk.Label(self.master, text="test")
        self.test_label.pack(side='bottom')
    
    def tb_click(self):
        self.stop = threading.Event()
        self.queue = queue.Queue( )
        thread = Rfid(self.queue, self.stop)
        thread.start()
        self.master.after(100, self.process_queue)
        self.master.after(10000, self.terminate)

    def process_queue(self):
        try:
            msg = self.queue.get(0)
            #print(str(msg))
            self.test_label.configure(text=str(msg))      
        except queue.Empty:
            self.master.after(100, self.process_queue)

    def terminate(self):
        if thread.is_alive():
            self.stop.set()

class Rfid(threading.Thread):
    
    def __init__(self, queue, stop):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.stop = stop

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.stop.isSet():
                print("abgeschalten")
                break
    
            reader = SimpleMFRC522()
            id, text = reader.read()
            print(str(id))  
            self.queue.put(str(text))
            GPIO.cleanup()
      
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Test")
main_ui = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to use `reader.read_no_block()` instead.  Save a reference time before the while loop. If no card detected by `reader.read_no_block()`, then check time elapsed since the reference time.  If time elapsed is greater than 10 seconds, break out the while loop.  If card is detected, update the reference time as current time.

Comment: Thank you very much, that works.
Now I only have the problem that the reader returns a "None" if it does not include an ID. When I try to check if it is "None" or "blank" it still always returns "TRUE". Is there a possible "if" to find out if the ID is a number?

Comment: It's done, my "None" query was wrong

Comment: One more suggestion: move `reader = SimpleMFRC522()` to before while loop and `GPIO.cleanup()` after while loop.

Comment: ok, right that makes more sense, thanks